# Running setup.py install for imread ... error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

**When using python, I encountered the code that needs to use the imread library. After opening cmd on Windows 10, type pip install imread to install the library, but the installation cannot be successful.**

**Hope someone can help me**

```
C:\Users\asus>pip install imread
Collecting imread
  Using cached imread-0.7.4.tar.gz (151 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in e:\python\lib\site-packages (from imread) (1.19.5)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for imread, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: imread
    Running setup.py install for imread ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'e:\python\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\asus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6d8vy2ja\\imread_6cef3c1ec76c45f5a9524c7a341656d6\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\asus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6d8vy2ja\\imread_6cef3c1ec76c45f5a9524c7a341656d6\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-z9mfhov0\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'e:\python\Include\imread'
         cwd: C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6d8vy2ja\imread_6cef3c1ec76c45f5a9524c7a341656d6\
    Complete output (86 lines):
    'pkg-config' 不是内部或外部命令，也不是可运行的程序
    或批处理文件。
    e:\python\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread
    copying imread\ijrois.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread
    copying imread\imread.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread
    copying imread\imread_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread
    copying imread\special.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread
    copying imread\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests
    copying imread\tests\test_bad.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests
    copying imread\tests\test_bmp.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests
    copying imread\tests\test_error.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests
    copying imread\tests\test_formats.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests
    copying imread\tests\test_imread.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests
    copying imread\tests\test_imread_from_blob.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests
    copying imread\tests\test_imsave.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests
    copying imread\tests\test_jpeg.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests
    copying imread\tests\test_png.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests
    copying imread\tests\test_rois.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests
    copying imread\tests\test_tiff.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests
    copying imread\tests\test_webp.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests
    copying imread\tests\test_xcf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests
    copying imread\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data
    copying imread\tests\data\0186-0099.roi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data
    copying imread\tests\data\1_webp_a.webp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data
    copying imread\tests\data\arange512_16bit.png -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data
    copying imread\tests\data\bit1.png -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data
    copying imread\tests\data\diag.xcf -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data
    copying imread\tests\data\error.jpg -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data
    copying imread\tests\data\error.png -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data
    copying imread\tests\data\error.tif -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data
    copying imread\tests\data\error.unknown -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data
    copying imread\tests\data\error.webp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data
    copying imread\tests\data\ghsystem_flame.jpg -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data
    copying imread\tests\data\good -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data
    copying imread\tests\data\good.png -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data
    copying imread\tests\data\mono.tif -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data
    copying imread\tests\data\palette_zero.png -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data
    copying imread\tests\data\py-installer-indexed.bmp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data
    copying imread\tests\data\rgba.png -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data
    copying imread\tests\data\rois.zip -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data
    copying imread\tests\data\stack.tiff -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data
    copying imread\tests\data\star1.bmp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data
    copying imread\tests\data\T -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files\TIFF
    copying imread\tests\data\bad-files\TIFF\00r00.tiff -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files\TIFF
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files\BMP
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files\BMP\00r
    copying imread\tests\data\bad-files\BMP\00r\00r00.bmp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files\BMP\00r
    copying imread\tests\data\bad-files\BMP\00r\00r01.bmp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files\BMP\00r
    copying imread\tests\data\bad-files\BMP\00r\00r02.bmp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files\BMP\00r
    copying imread\tests\data\bad-files\BMP\00r\00r03.bmp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files\BMP\00r
    copying imread\tests\data\bad-files\BMP\00r\00r04.bmp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files\BMP\00r
    copying imread\tests\data\bad-files\BMP\00r\00r05.bmp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files\BMP\00r
    copying imread\tests\data\bad-files\BMP\00r\00r06.bmp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files\BMP\00r
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\00r
    copying imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\00r\00r00.lsm -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\00r
    copying imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\00r\00r01.lsm -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\00r
    copying imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\00r\00r02.lsm -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\00r
    copying imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\00r\00r03.lsm -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\00r
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\01r
    copying imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\01r\01r00.lsm -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\01r
    copying imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\01r\01r01.lsm -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\01r
    copying imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\01r\01r02.lsm -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\01r
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\02r
    copying imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\02r\02r00.lsm -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\02r
    copying imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\02r\02r01.lsm -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\02r
    copying imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\02r\02r02.lsm -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\02r
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\03w
    copying imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\03w\03w00.lsm -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\03w
    copying imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\03w\03w01.lsm -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\03w
    copying imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\03w\03w02.lsm -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\03w
    copying imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\03w\03w03.lsm -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\imread\tests\data\bad-files\LSM\03w
    running build_ext
    building 'imread._imread' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'e:\python\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\asus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6d8vy2ja\\imread_6cef3c1ec76c45f5a9524c7a341656d6\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\asus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6d8vy2ja\\imread_6cef3c1ec76c45f5a9524c7a341656d6\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-z9mfhov0\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'e:\python\Include\imread' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you read the error message properly ? `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+is+required

Comment: I read the error message properly. I try to open the URL(http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools),but haven't any reply.

Comment: Try https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#imread